# List Comprehension Over Pandas Dataframe Rows

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension, dataframe

I can't understand why this snippet of code:

```
df = PA.DataFrame()
[df.append(aFunction(x)) for x in aPandaSeries]
```

does not give me the same DataFrame (df) as:

```
df = PA.DataFrame()
for x in xrange(len(aPandaSeries)):
        df = df.append(aFunction(aPandaSeries[x]))
```

I am trying to pythonise the second section by using the first section, but df has far fewer rows in the former than the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things...

1. .append() method returns None. So df = df.append() will set df to None value.
2. List comprehensions are useful to filter or process a list of values, so you generally wouldn't use .append() with a list comprehension. It makes more sense to rewrite the 2nd line in first snippet as:

`for x in aPandaSeries:
        df.append(aFunction(x))`

Comment: Perfect - thank you. Though I think you meant: for x in aPandaSeries: df = df.append(aFunction(x))

Comment: No, you don't really ever need to assign return value of .append() to anything, because it's always None. df.append() modifies df in-place. That's an important distinction. Lists and dicts have a lot of methods that modify them in-place.